# Does Bing 2.0 API support multiple queries in 1 request?

Tags: java, web-services, bing, bing-api

Can I send more than 1 search request via JSON SourceType in a Bing 2.0 api call? I'm creating a custom library against Bing because I'm not on .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Only multiple sources.